# How to display the first row, depending on a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am supposed to build a query that displays if a product passed quality test the first time. for example if product# 1234 fails the first test then don't display the value. I am running SQL Server 2005. I am thinking maybe using a `COALESCE` statement, or case when statement, any help would be appreciated. here is some sample data:

```
product#  test result   datetime
1102494    Fail         20111129:07:57:50.203
1102494    pass         20111130:16:48:28.140
1102496    pass         20111129:11:09:32.140
1102498    pass         20111129:08:21:10.218
```

Comment: do you mean you want to return a result set of unique products, all of which passed? or just one product?

Comment: I am trying to display all of the products that passed on the first test. So if the pipe originally fails, i don't want to display it at all. eg product# 1102494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show only the first result, and only if the first result is a 'pass'.

```
select *
  from (
select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by [product#] order by [datetime] desc)
  from tests
     ) x
 where rn=1 and result = 'pass';
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you select where test_result = 'pass'?? Maybe I misunderstood your question

Comment: Well that is what i originally thought, my boss does not want products that failed the first test to be displayed. If i did a where test_result ='pass' then product# 1102494 would show up, which failed the first test